# When to use which strategy in Afterwind?

Tags: afterwind

I am playing [Afterwind](http://afterwind.com/home/) quite regularly nowadays and I was wondering when one should use which strategy. For example, if you are surrounded by a lot of other players maybe you should use prefect defense but lack of expansion will mean you will get bankrupt very soon, so maybe Imperialist will be better strategy because it will reduce the cost of all units and let u afford more even though units will have low hit points than usual. Even Gurilla warfare won't be a bad strategy under the circumstance.

So what strategy should be used in what situation keeping in mind the number of player surrounding you, starting limit (high or low), and special scenario like WW2 or WW3?

Answer (score 3):

PD Would be good, Not imperial. PD Is so cheap, you will never run out of money. try your hardest to ally with the closest person to your capital.

GW Is always good in small games, even if you don't have a lot of money.